# After inserting a row in mysql, the latest row climbs up based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Insertion of a row in a table does not make it the last row, but instead inserts a row above certain rows.

```
insert into table (revenueSB40, revenueSM40, sum, eedate) 
      values(100,200,300,'2015-05-17');
```

Last few rows:

```
| 41200 | 80620 | 121820 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 |   
| 35440 | 86100 | 121540 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 |   
| 30160 | 62600 | 92760  | 2015-05-13 00:00:00 |  
| 19800 | 31780 | 51580  | 2015-05-16 00:00:00 |  
| 58480 | 90860 | 149340 | 2015-05-15 00:00:00 |  
| 59440 | 52500 | 111940 | 2015-05-14 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: How it does not? Show your table structure and possibly the last few rows?

Comment: cannot share a snapshot. Ir un the following query insert into table (revenueSB40, revenueSM40, sum, eedate) values(100,200,300,'2015-05-17');

Comment: Just text would suffice.

Comment: |       41200 |       80620 | 121820 | 2015-05-11 00:00:00 |
|       35440 |       86100 | 121540 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00 |
|       30160 |       62600 |  92760 | 2015-05-13 00:00:00 |
|       19800 |       31780 |  51580 | 2015-05-16 00:00:00 |
|       58480 |       90860 | 149340 | 2015-05-15 00:00:00 |
|       59440 |       52500 | 111940 | 2015-05-14 00:00:00

Comment: You can edit your question and add them there. What's the table's primary key?

Comment: What is "above" and "last" in a RDBS, please ???

Comment: when you insert a row in sql it gets added after the last row. In this case, it moves up accordin to the date

Comment: Does your table only have these 4 columns?

Comment: Yes it only has these four columns

Comment: And which one of them is the `primary key`? And insert a new row with date `2015-05-17` and see where it ends up? You're just using a simple `select * from table` to get the output right?

Comment: yes i use this query to get data, select * from table and there's no primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDBMS tables represent unordered sets. There is no such thing as "the first row of a table" or "the last row of the table". When you issue a `select` statement without an `order by` clause, the database may return the rows in  whatever order it deems fit ("fit", usually meaning "fastest"). Even if the data in the table does not change the order of these results may change depending on internal caches' state or maintenance operations performed (e.g., rebuilding indexes).

Although it is common for a database to return the rows in the order they were inserted (especially for small tables without any indexes), it is definitely not mandatory, and you should **not** rely on this behavior.

If you want any guarantee on the order of rows returned, you must explicitly state the ordering you require with an `order by` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `table`
ORDER BY revenueSB40
```